# Need help identifying a bad IC

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

Top board on a Bose Revolve. The battery PCB quit. As I was testing, I messed up this chip on the top board. I’m not completely sure what it does, but I’m guessing it’s a battery protection IC.

The chip blew out so I can’t read all the code on it. It looks like the top line is QUG or QVG or something like that. The middle line looks like FCK. The last line I can only make out the last few letters. **Y6 maybe *AY6? There may be more letters/numbers then 4, I’m not sure.

Any help identifying this would be awesome. I’ll add the pin pitch and IC physical dimensions in a little bit when I get the digital caliper out. But it is really small.

I’ve included a picture of the IC and can add a picture of the whole board if it helps.

[image: Blown IC][1]]

Comment: There seems to be a few photos on the web. maybe they might help

Comment: Thanks for the answers so far, I have searched the web for pictures, but none are detailed enough to show any lettering on the IC. ‍♂️

Comment: It got a heat sink so replacing it by hand will be a pain. You'll need a desoldering hot air gun. I'd cut off the legs first since the part is toast anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a [TPS62172](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/slvsat8b/slvsat8b.pdf) 3.3V switching regulator (buck converter.)

[image]

The package appears to match your part:

[image]

This circuit shows a typical setup:

[image]

SW and VOS are pins 6 and 7, which have an inductor between them just like on your circuit board:

[image]

Comment: JRE you are a genius. And after closer inspection with the microscope, it doesn’t have any legs. Those are actually solder to the pads on the side of the chip just as seen on the tps62172. And Lundin already meantioned the heat sink on the belly. Thank you all very much. I now just have to order the chip and start checking out what else I messed up 

Comment: Also I measured the chip, it is 2mm x 2mm with a .5mm pitch on the pads. As seen on the tps62172.